# Backup do banco de dados ao clicar em um link

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso que um superusuário do meu sistema exporte o banco de dados ao clicar em "backup", e force o download do script dele por PHP, como faz o phpMyAdmin. Isso é possível? Se sim, como? Se não, tem algum jeito de eu fazer algo parecido?

Comment: E por que precisa do PhpMyAdmin? Está um pouco difícil de entender a sua pergunta amigo, tem como explicar melhor o que você precisa?

Comment: Estou desenvolvendo uma apliação web, certo, no phpmyadmin tenho na base de dados após seleciona-la posso clicar em exportar, ele gera um script dela com seus conteúdos, eu quero essa função exatamente, mas em outra página, do mesmo jeito gerando esse script e fazendo o download automático.  Invés de ter que logar no PHPMYADMIN e clicar lá...

Comment: PhpMyAdmin não é o "local" que fica guardado os dados, é apenas um CLIENTE gerenciador, ou seja é apenas um software para acessar o servidor mysql via PHP-API. Se estar a criar um software de backup, a unica coisa que vai precisar é usar PHP-API, no caso `mysqli` ou `pdo`. Note que você pode usar o phpmyadmin, mas ele está escrito sob uma licença GNU e você deve tomar cuidado com o uso do software inapropriadamente. Realmente sem querer lhe ofender, mas você precisa aprender o minimo da linguagem que vai usar para poder usá-la. :)

Comment: To citando o PMA somente como exemplo cara. A minha duvida em si é uma maneira a qual eu posso gerar o script do meu banco para backup, se já existe alguma API que facilite ou ...?

Comment: Quando de referi a API estou me referindo ao próprio PHP, como o `mysqli` que é uma função ou classe do próprio php, chamamos de API, pois é parte de uma "extension" que pode ser usada ou não no php. Por isto disse que você deve aprender o minimo do linguagem que vai usar, pois você está confundindo a maioria das características desta linguagem.

Answer (score 1):

O MySQL vem com um utilitário exatamente para isso, que é o [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html). Localize esse arquivo na máquina e guarde o caminho dele. No PHP você pode executar esse utilitário com [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), e salvar o backup em disco. Salvando em um local acessível pelo *webserver*, é só apontar o browser pra lá. Exemplo:

```
<?php
$caminhoDoMysqldump = "caminho/do/mysqldump/no/seu/servidor";
$usuario = "usuário do mysql";
$senha = "senha do mysql";
$banco = "seu_banco";
$saida = "/var/www/meuSite/arquivos/backup.sql"; // por exemplo

// Gera o backup e salva em disco
exec("$caminhoDoMysqldump --user=$usuario --password=$senha $banco > $saida");

// Redireciona o browser para o arquivo gerado
header('Location: http://www.meusite.com/arquivos/backup.sql');
exit;
```

Também é possível fazer o mesmo sem gerar o arquivo em disco, com o [`passthru`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php), que é bem similar ao `exec` mas redireciona a saída para o PHP. Exemplo retirado de uma [resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19575620/825789):

```
<?php

$DBUSER="user";
$DBPASSWD="password";
$DATABASE="user_db";

$filename = "backup-" . date("d-m-Y") . ".sql.gz";
$mime = "application/x-gzip";

header( "Content-Type: " . $mime );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"' );

$cmd = "mysqldump -u $DBUSER --password=$DBPASSWD $DATABASE | gzip --best";   

passthru( $cmd );

exit(0);
?>
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54231/discussion-on-answer-by-bfavaretto-backup-do-banco-de-dados-ao-clicar-em-um-link)